# Bibtex parser in Haskell

Tags: haskell, bibtex

I am using parser bibtex for Haskell (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bibtex).
The parser works great.
But I cannot parse special characters (like "P{\u{a}}lt{\u{a}}nea").
I need the characters to be encoded UTF-8.
I tried using texSequence (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bibtex-0.1.0.6/docs/src/Text-BibTeX-Parse.html#texSequence) but with no success.
How can I parse special characters to UTF-8?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain the problem more clearly? Many of us are not fluent in TeX.